# How To Base PHP Include Off of Current Pagename?

Tags: php

I'm currently hardcoding an include into my pages and its a lot of work everytime I want to create a new page. Currently, my url is like this:

```
http://example.com/folder/one-z-pagename.php?var1=one&var2=two
```

and in **one-z-pagename.php** I have an include that looks like this:

```
include("lander-a-pagename.php");
```

So what I want to do is instead of hardcoding the file into the page like above, I want to grab `one-z-pagename.php` without the `?var1=one&var2=two`  from the url, erase the first 6 characters which is `one-z-` and replace it with `lander-a-`.

How do I do something like this?

Answer (score 0):

use `parse_url` and `basename` to get filename then `str_replace`

```
$url= parse_url('http://example.com/folder/one-z-pagename.php?var1=one&var2=two');
$file = basename($url['path']);
$newfile = str_replace('one-z-','lander-a-',$file);
echo $newfile;
```

output : `lander-a-pagename.php`

Comment: the domain url will be dynamic, so how do i just grab the filename?

Comment: use `parse_url` and `basename` to get filename

Answer (score 0):

It can be achive by many method, have a look on below two methods:

Method 1:

```
$current_script_name = basename(__FILE__);
$include_script_name = 'lander-a-'.substr($current_script_name, 6);
```

Method 2:

```
$current_script_name = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
$current_script_name = end(explode('/', $current_script_name));
$include_script_name = 'lander-a-'.substr($current_script_name, 6);
//OR
$include_script_name = str_replace('one-z', 'lander-a', $current_script_name);
```

variable `$include_script_name` contains required filename which you want to include.

Hope this will help.